# zip() with optional parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

I'm looking to iterate over optional parameters, a simplistic example:

```py
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = {'function':['add','add','multiply']}

for i in zip(a, b, *c):
    if i['function'] == 'add':
        print(i[0] + i[1])
    elif i['function'] == 'multiply':
        print(i[0] * i[1])
```

This currently doesn't work, but I'm unsure why after reading the * notation here:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

I feel the iterator should return 2 indices from i, alongside any named values from the dictionary?

How do I properly implement this logic?

### Update 2019-10-16

Thanks for all you replies but I don't think I have explained my idea properly.

My ultimate goal is to iterate formatting values from a dictionary:

```py
labels = ['Car', 'Van', 'Bike']

font_list = {'bold':[True, True, False],
             'italic'=[False, True, True]}

font = {'underline':False}


for i in zip(labels, *font_list):
    if 'bold' in i:
        bold = i['bold']
    else:
        bold = font['bold']
    addLabelToPlot(label=i[0], bold=bold, ...)
    ...
```

If the format is different for each label then it will be placed in the `font_list` dictionary, else it will be placed in the `font` dictionary.

Comment: zip returns list so you can't use `i['function']` but `i[2]` but it gives one char and it rather would need `zip(..., c['function'])`

Comment: This does not work. zip take iterable with the same length, *c return key of the dictionary, in you case only one key, so zip will stop after the first loop. Know, could you be more precise on what you want, because nothing work in your exemple loop. I is a tuple, i['function'] does not work.

Comment: @fred I am still unsure what you are trying achieve, if you can add the expected output from the code it would be great

Answer (score 2):

You should use `c['function']`

```
 for i in zip(a, b, c['function']):
```

and later you would have `i[2]` instead of `i['function']`

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = {'function':['add','add','multiply']}

for i in zip(a, b, c['function']):
    if i[2] == 'add':
        print(i[0] + i[1])
    elif i[2] == 'multiply':
        print(i[0] * i[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because your code gives the following when doing

```py
print(list(zip(a, b, *c))
```

that gives:

```py
[(1, 4, 'f'), (2, 5, 'u'), (3, 6, 'n')]
```

You see we only match the first char in the string, but 
If we instead do like this

```py
for i in zip(a, b, c['function']):
```

We get the following output:

```py
[(1, 4, 'add'), (2, 5, 'add'), (3, 6, 'multiply')]
```

and then the code can look like this:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = {'function': ['add', 'add', 'multiply']}

for i in zip(a, b, c['function']):
    if i[2] == 'add':
        print(i[0] + i[1])
    elif i[2] == 'multiply':
        print(i[0] * i[1])
```

It might make more sense for you to unpack the values explicitly to make it more understandable to read the code  in the following manner, this way be get named variables instead of having to rely on indexes that can be confusing to look at.

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = {'function': ['add', 'add', 'multiply']}

for n1, n2, operation in zip(a, b, c['function']):
    if operation == 'add':
        print(n2 + n2)
    elif operation == 'multiply':
        print(n1 * n2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = {'function':['add','add','multiply']}
def deee(a,b,function):
    for i in zip(a, b, function):
    if i[2] == 'add':
        print(i[0] + i[1])
    elif i[2] == 'multiply':
        print(i[0] * i[1])
deee(a,b,**c)
```

you can use like this